# Is it possible for two different continuous functions to intersect along a finite domain?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity, taylor-expansion

Can you have two continuous functions that intersect continuously along a finite domain $[a,b]$ (strictly not an infinite region), that is **not piecewise, or absolute valued?** More specifically, it must be differentiable at every point in the domain. It seems intuitive that it isn’t possible. I’ve tried reframing it as: if two functions intersect along a finite region, then they must be identical functions.

I’ve thought of taking a Taylor series path, and saying that as the number of terms of each Taylor series approaches infinity, the density of roots (intersections) doesn’t approach infinity.

Also derivatives seem intuitive, that there must be a discontinuity in the derivative at each endpoint, but I’m not sure if that implies discontinuity of the original function.

Comment: $|x^2-1|$ and $-x^2+1$ are both continuous, and coincide on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: The assertion "if two functions intersect along a finite interval, then they must be identical" will be correct if you reword it as "if two functions intersect along a finite interval, then they must be identical _on that interval_".

Comment: @dxiv Ah. I should have mentioned, no absolute values, since these inherently have a discontinuity in the derivative.

Comment: @Simplex1 $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$. So if you are disallowing absolute value, are you disallowing $\sqrt{\phantom{x}}$? Disallowing $\phantom{x}^2$? Where does it end?

Comment: @Simplex1 Then [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4145106/edit) the question and state all requirements. Btw, it's easy to "round the corners" around the intersections as to make it differentiable.

Comment: @dxiv Ok. I’ve made the requirement that the functions must be differentiable for all points in the domain.

Comment: all functions are piecewise functions

Comment: @Simplex1 No, you made two different unrelated requirements. Differentiability has nothing to do with piecewise or absolute values. You should decide what the question is that you really mean to ask.

Comment: Take your favorite continuous function $h(x)$ that is $0$ on $[a,b]$ and non-zero otherwise (and satisfies your other conditions). Then, define $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

This function $$g(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x}&\text{if }x>0\\ 0&\text{if }-1\le x\le 0\\ e^{1/(x+1)}&\text{if }x<-1\end{cases}$$

is $C^\infty$, and it coincides with $0$ on $[-1,0]$.

Comment: I think OP asks for a function that is defined without piecewise notation. Of course, it is often possible to present a function like this one without piecewise notation.

Comment: @alex.jordan I guess I could try my party tricks, but right now I'm more in the mood for watching other people's party tricks (perhaps even for a certain someone to improve his understanding of a subject, you never know :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=1$, the constant function.

Let $g(x)=\sqrt{(x-1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2}$.

$f=g$ on $[0,1]$ and $f\neq g$ on $\mathbb{R}-[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Letting

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x^{4}-4x^{3}-2x^{2}+12x+9}+x^{2}-2x-3$$

and
$$ g(x)= 0,$$

we can see that the graphs of both functions intersect on $[-1, 3]$.